# Can I use my iPhone earbuds as a microphone on my Mac in TinyChat?

Tags: iphone, macbook, microphone, earbuds

I have the iPhone/iPod in-ear headphones and the first aluminum unibody MacBook. So, I can control the volume and track in iTunes using the buttons on the headphones.

My question is - can I use the microphone as well? I have been doing video conferencing via TinyChat, and although I can hear the audio out my headphones it doesn't seem to be picking up the headphone mic - it's using the Mac's built-in mic instead.

Comment: When I plug in my iPhone earbuds the microphone in the Sound prefs pane switches from internal to external, and the mic switches over for all apps. I can't switch back to the Mac's mic without removing the headphones. Do you see any change in your sound input devices pane when plugging in the headphones? Do they work correctly in the phone/iPod?

Answer (score 2):

> The headphones’ built-in microphone
>   appears as the input device
>   “Microphone port” in the Sound
>   preference pane.

So I guess you have to select it in the Sound prefences pane (Option+F5)